# Как сверстать такой блок с такими фигурами?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, не поснимаю как можно сделать такие желтые фигуры в блоке ...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: желтый `div` справа, белый `div` на нем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например вот так:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 50px solid yellow;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```